# Xubuntu 14.04 hangs while browsing using Chromium or Firefox

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, chromium

My Xubuntu 14.04 hangs too much when i start to use browsers like chromium or firefox. I dont know the reasons,but i think i encounter this problem everytime i use a browser. I am using Xubuntu on my samsung netbook( 1gb ram). 
I have already tried a few tweaks like decreasing the swap memory or something and it didnt solve my problem.

I have a feeling, this happens because i am always running into unresponsive pages in chromium or in firefox non-responsive scripts.

i have seen the browser support pages. They didnt help me either.

I would be very happy if somebody could tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe disabling the adobe flash player can solve it.

in the chrome enter= chrome://plugins (i dont have chromium,so if dosent work

replace chrome vs chromium)and disable flash player or ppapi flash)

and for firefox go to addons and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some check points that I use to improve responsiveness.

- On Firefox, check the add-ons consumption with ... the **addons-memory**
  addon (then disable any addon that shows high consumption.)
- If you use AdBlock (quite heavy), replace it with **ublock origin** or µblock (available on
  Chromium as well)
- Optimize swappiness : 
  `echo vm.swappiness=5 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf 
  echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf 
  sudo sysctl -p`
- If you use wifi, ensure that you
  uses WPA2 AES encryption.
- Ultimately, on low RAM systems (<2Go) my experience is that 32bits OS are more responsive.(There, you can try to add RAM or.. to do a fresh install with a 32bits Xubuntu (or Lubuntu)